# WPF - Create a border with line style as a saw-tooth (gear)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to draw a border or rectangle like a bill payment on shop.
[image]

For make it's as real, I need to draw a shredding effect with the bottom is a saw-tooth line instead of a normal border.

Would you please to give me some advises?

Answer (score -2):

Forget borders. Terminate the bottom side of the white area as a normal rectangle, but stack immediately at bottom an image (e.g. PNG) with the perforation strip.

That's the easiest way, unless you need something that adapts to the rectangle's width.